# Postgresql - percentage from query columns

Tags: postgresql

I have this query which displays information about the frequency of subject appearing in case A and B and the appearance's percentage of case A.

```
select subject, 
count(subject) as frequency,
count(case when result='OK' then 1 else null end) as case_a,
count(case when result='NG' then 1 else null end) as case_b,
round(
(
 (count(case when result='OK' then 1 else null end)*100.00)/count(subject)),4)
)
from test
group by subject
```

I'm guessing if there's a better-classier way of calculating the percentage without having to apply the count-case a second time.

```
round(((case_a*100.00) / frequency),4)
```

Tried to reference the columns like this^ but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, you can't reference column aliases like this. One way around it is to put all your calculations in a sub-query:

```
SELECT subject, frequency, case_a, case_b, ROUND(case_a * 100.0 / frequency, 4)
FROM   (SELECT    subject,
                  COUNT(subject) AS frequency,
                  COUNT(CASE WHEN result = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS case_a,
                  COUNT(CASE WHEN result = 'NG' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS case_b
         FROM     test
         GROUP BY subject) t
```

EDIT:
As a side note, if none of the conditions in a `case` expression are met, `null` is returned, so you could have slightly shorter expressions. Then effect is ultimately the same, so it's mainly a matter of taste:

```
SELECT subject, frequency, case_a, case_b, ROUND(case_a * 100.0 / frequency, 4)
FROM   (SELECT    subject,
                  COUNT(subject) AS frequency,
                  COUNT(CASE result WHEN 'OK' THEN 1 END) AS case_a,
                  COUNT(CASE result WHEN 'NG' THEN 1 END) AS case_b
         FROM     test
         GROUP BY subject) t
```

Comment: That sub-query approach is certainly interesting, thanks.